# Understand the output of a C code with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand, what's going on in this program. The output is `-121 3`. How do we get this output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 903;
    char *p = (char *) &a;
    printf("%d ",*p++);
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

[Runnable Code at ideone](http://ideone.com/Ve7s3T)

Comment: What a weird idea to cast `int*` to `char*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what happens...

---

`903` equals `0x387` in hex.

```
int a = 903;
```

---

You make a pointer to it, and cast it to a signed char pointer:

```
char *p = (char *) &a;
```

---

That now points to the `0x387`'s LSB, which reads `0x87`, and when treated as signed char, you get `-121`. Then you advance to the MSB (by incrementing the pointer).

```
printf("%d ",*p++);
```

---

Now you read the MSB, which is 3.

```
printf("%d",*p);
```

---

However, it's not a very good idea to cast `int*` to `char*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation but i didn't understand the part where you said, `0x87` is treated as signed char?

Comment: Oh cool.. ignore, got it. Converted it to binary and taken it as 1's compliment form

Comment: yep that's exactly it

Comment: For the one that comes checking the problem... To be clear, I had taken 2's compliment which gives the expected answer..